# AWS - IAM Roles between Fargate instances and other AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

Here I have a task definition for Fargate to launch a microservice inside. It isnt important what this microservice does. My question is about the two properties below:

```
ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
```

```
TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
```

and here is the TaskDefinition for Fargate/Microservice, again the microservice here isnt important.

```
TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties: 
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - "FARGATE"
      ContainerDefinitions: 
        - Environment:
            - Name: DEST_BUCKET
              Value: !Ref BucketName
            - Name: SOURCE_QUEUE_URL
              Value: !Ref ConversionQueue
          Essential: True
          Image: !Sub '${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${EcrRepo}'
          LogConfiguration: 
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options: 
              awslogs-group : !Ref LogGroup
              awslogs-region : !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-stream-prefix : ecs
          Name: 'conversion'
      Cpu: '256'
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
      Family: 'conversion-taskdefinition'
      Memory: '512'
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
```

and here is the ECSTaskRole:

```
  ECSTaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Description: 'IAM Role for conversion-service tasks'
      RoleName: 'conversion-taskrole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow 
                Action: 
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                Resource: !Join
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                    - !Ref S3Bucket
                    - /*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - sqs:*"
                Resource: !GetAtt ConversionQueue.Arn
```

So if I understand the IAM and FARGATE relationship properly, the Fargate instances specified in the task definition assumes the ECSTaskRole which defines what the instances are allowed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fargate instances specified in the task definition assumes the ECSTaskRole which defines what the instances are allowed to do?

Yes.  `TaskRoleArn` role is assumed by the fargate task, so  that your **application** running on the fargate can interact with AWS, e.g. access S3.

`ExecutionRoleArn` is for the ECS service itself, so that the service, not your application, can access AWS resources required to actually run your image, e.g. access ECR to download your docker image.

Comment: ok so for 'ExecutionRoleArn' is pointing at 'AssumeRolePolicyDocument' which then points at 'Service:  - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com' so that ECS service can access the necessary AWS services to create my Fargate instances?

Comment: @masafood Yes. In fact often  `TaskRoleArn` and `ExecutionRoleArn` can be one and the same role.

Comment: ok and final question, what is the 'path' property for??

Comment: @masafood What path is, is explained in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html).